# Matlab can not set to negative, -1

Tags: matlab, negative-number

I want to replace certain values in matrix/vector to -1, but can't seem to be able to.

```
x = [1 5 6; 2 4 3; 3 4 2; 4 2 1];
z = x(:,1) == 4 % get result I want
z =

 0
 0
 0
 1

changem(z,-1,0) % changem doesn't work

ans =

 1
 1
 1
 1
```

same if I make array in changem

```
changem(z,[-1 1],[0 1])
ans =

 1
 1
 1
 1
```

This also doesn't work

```
 z(1) = -1
 z =

   1
   0
   0
   1
```

Why can't I manipulate the vector to get the following values

```
ans =

 -1
 -1
 -1
 1
```

This approach works, but an answer to the previous question would be great, thanks.

```
z = x(:,1) ~= 4; 
z = z * -1; 
z = changem(z,1,0)
ans =

 -1
 -1
 -1
 1
```

Comment: What is changem? A function?  What does it do?

Comment: Strange that this is marked duplicate when it obviously not based on question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a logical operation returns values from the binary set {0, 1}. if you want these as {-1, +1} one simple transformation is to multiply by 2, then subtract by one.

```
z = (x(1, :)  == 4)*2 - 1
```

Comment: @crowdedComputeer so the assignment to z is a binary set and only multiplication operation changes the type, and this is why changem or assignment to an index doesn't work. Fascinating.

Comment: yes. the "==" operation returns logical types that behave differently than numerical types. the transformation I suggested takes advantage of the fact that Matlab is dynamically typed and automatically promotes logicals to doubles when you apply multiplication.

Comment: @crowdedComputeeer You're confusing dynamic typing and weak typing. The fact that MATLAB allows you to apply `+` on logicals and performs implicit conversions indicates weak typing, but has nothing to do with dynamic typing. For instance, C is statically typed but performs similar implicit type conversions.

Comment: touché @Jubobs, that'll teach me to talk typing off the cuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `changeme` is, and therefore can't comment on results of that function.

In Matlab and a variety of environments (eg. C, C++), zero evaluates to logical false, and anything besides zero evaluates to a logical true. For example in Matlab, `logical(x)` will convert a double array `x` to a binary/logical array. `logical(-1)` evaluates to 1 (i.e. true). If `z` is a logical array and you make the assignment:

```
z(1) = -1;
```

What happens is the double `-1` gets converted to a binary value, which is `true` (i.e. 1) since everything besides 0 gets converted to true 1. Then 1 is assigned to the first index of `z`. All is working as it should.